# How to make HTML/CSS slideshow background fade?

Tags: javascript, html, css, background, slideshow

I was wondering how you make a background slideshow fade into other photos like a regular slideshow. I've tried many codes and have yet to be successful.

Now, I have a code to make the background change to different photos which works well, but it doesn't fade. Is there anyway to add this?

Here is the code

```
<html>
<head>

<style>


body{
/*Remove below line to make bgimage NOT fixed*/
background-attachment:fixed;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
/*Use center center in place of 300 200 to center bg image*/
background-position: 0 0; background-
}
</style>

<script language="JavaScript1.2">

//Background Image Slideshow- © Dynamic Drive (www.dynamicdrive.com)
//For full source code, 100's more DHTML scripts, and TOS,
//visit http://www.dynamicdrive.com

//Specify background images to slide
var bgslides=new Array()
bgslides[0]="http://i892.photobucket.c…

bgslides[1]="http://i892.photobucket.c…

bgslides[2]="http://i892.photobucket.c…

//Specify interval between slide (in miliseconds)
var speed=2000

//preload images
var processed=new Array()
for (i=0;i<bgslides.length;i++){
processed[i]=new Image()
processed[i].src=bgslides[i]
}

var inc=-1

function slideback(){
if (inc<bgslides.length-1)
inc++
else
inc=0
document.body.background=processed[inc…
}

if (document.all||document.getElementById)
window.onload=new Function('setInterval("slideback()",spee…

</script>

</head>

</html>
```

If you have any suggestions please let me know. Also, I am not the greatest at coding and don't have a clue about JavaScript, so please explain what to do.

Comment: I would rather use a DIV for the background image and have a low z-index value for it. Then simply slide through the pictures using jquery or whatever other library. That's only an idea though ;)

Answer (score 12):

[Working example on jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/htmled/2kkHH/)

Use this code instead: (note that you'll need to load [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) in order for this code to work)

HTML

```
<div class="fadein">
    <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8359/8450229021_9d660578b4_n.jpg">
    <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8510/8452880627_0e673b24d8_n.jpg">
    <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8108/8456552856_a843b7a5e1_n.jpg">
    <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8230/8457936603_f2c8f48691_n.jpg">
    <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8329/8447290659_02c4765928_n.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.fadein {
    position:relative;
    height:320px;
    width:320px;
}

.fadein img {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
```

JavaScript

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();

setInterval(function () {
    $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut()
                             .next('img')
                             .fadeIn()
                             .end()
                             .appendTo('.fadein');
}, 4000); // 4 seconds
});
</script>
```

Comment: All you need to do is include that block of JavaScript in the code above in your HTML page (at the bottom before the </body). Also, be sure to add the CSS to your stylesheet.

Comment: Great solution htmled!

One question though: How could I combine this to work with dynamic width (100%) of the images?

I tried updating your jsFiddle, but then the text is placed behind the images.

See http://jsfiddle.net/2kkHH/340/

Comment: Doesn't exactly answer your question, but I made CSS-only derivative version at http://codepen.io/denilsonsa/pen/mpiCj (and see also [this question at Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/css/comments/275rdk/trying_to_create_a_background_slideshow_for_my/))

Comment: Have any way to add smooth fadein or css animation ?

Answer (score -2):

Inside the Css:

width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    position: fixed;

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.