# CSS and dynamic width (100%) together with slideshow

Tags: css

I've created a simple image fader using the technique in the answer from [How to make HTML/CSS slideshow background fade?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14867614/how-to-make-html-css-slideshow-background-fade)

However this solution requires the images to be of a fixed size. Once I add dynamic width (width=100%), the images overlay the text.

http://jsfiddle.net/2kkHH/340/

```
.fadein {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
}
```

Any suggestions how to have width=100% and at the same time avoid the images overlaying the text?

Comment: only you need to add height into your .fadein class and will work fine. and height should be height of large image.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the text to be positioned:

http://jsfiddle.net/jonigiuro/2kkHH/346/

```
p {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Also, text should always be contained in some tag (p, span, etc..)

Answer (score 0):

You have to give a fixed height and width to the container `div`. Unless that is done, how will your images be 100%? I mean 100% of what? The parent of images is `div` and hence 100% of that `div`.

See this updated fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/2kkHH/350/**

If you make your `div` 100%, then 100% of what? In this case it will take 100% of your page.

Answer (score 0):

Set the position of `.fadein img` also relative.

```
.fadein img {
    position:relative;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert these two lines of code

```
$('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
var h = $('.fadein :first-child').height(); // line to add 1
$('.fadein').height(h); // line to add 2
```

and everything will start working - http://jsfiddle.net/5Ugkr/

The reason is that container `div` does not deduce its height from its absolute positioned `img` children, so you must set the height 'manually'.