# Bug with a slider animation

Tags: html, css, animation, slider

I'm using this fade slider:

http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/284/index.html

That's exactly what I m looking for but as you probably can see, there is sometimes a little bug when the text go back to the right: a piece of the text div stay stuck and then disappears..

Here is the CSS:

http://css.dzone.com/articles/css3-fade-slider.

Do you know how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

Can't replicate the bug. there is a jfiddle with your code and runs well.

```
jsfiddle.net/3knqp6bo/
```

give more details in case.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I don t get it. The bug is on the site and also on mine, but not on jsfiddle...

Comment: try with different browers, maybe it's an idea.

Comment: You re right. Im on Chrome. I ve just tried with IE11 and it doesn t even show the slider!! There is a problem with that...

Comment: i tried on chrome and i have not the problem, try to clean browser chache or update it

Comment: I finally don 't use this slider anymore cuz it seems keyframes dont work on IE. I've found this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14867614/how-to-make-html-css-slideshow-background-fade